# Making C++ COM classes more test-friendly

Tags: c++, com, code-testing

Our code-base has a lot of COM objects, so typically we'll have something like:

```
//this is the IDL-generated IGetTime interface header
#include "gettime.h"

//our COM class implementation of IGetTime
class CGetTime : public IGetTime
{
  public:
    CGetTime(CGetTimeCF &factory,...); //COM-specific constructor params
    /* IUnknown */
    STDMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, LPVOID FAR * ppv);
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef();
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release();

    /* IGetTime */
    STDMETHODIMP GetTheTime(); //
};
```

The way the constructor and a few other things are set up, this class is only easily usable through COM... you *can* hack a way to create the object but it tends to be flaky. I many cases though, the actual functionality of the class might be usable without COM... and this would also be more easily testable if you could do `new CGetTime();`

I wondered about having something like this as a pattern:

```
class CGetTimeBase
{
 public:
  STDMETHODIMP GetTheTime();
};

class CGetTime : public IGetTime, public CGetTimeBase
{
...
};
```

Is this a good approach, or is there a better way to have a 'plain C++' class providing the core functionality, and a COM class doing the COM stuff? To minimise amount of code to write I'd rather not introduce wrapper methods, I think, but have the actual implementation method in the non-COM class so it's automatically present in the COM class.

Thoughts?
};

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where I work, we chose to separate core `C++` classes from the `COM` ones for several reasons:

1. This is **easier to maintain**. People that don't know `COM` much can focus on writing core classes and people who do know `COM` can safely wrap the core classes, without caring about the underlying implementation.
2. **Code reusability**. This might not be a requirement for you, but since the core classes are decoupled from the `COM` ones, we case use them directly in `C++` projects, where `COM` is not needed.
3. **Core testing**. Since the logic is separated from the interface, you can proceed to minimal tests easily. You no longer wonder: "Where is my leak ? Is it a legitimate leak in my core logic or something related to `COM`?" Core classes can be tested independently and efficiently.

This increases both the number of files and the compilation time, but I (we) think it worth it.

Comment: Yes these are essentially the thoughts prompting this question. But I was wondering about the implementation... in my approach there's the C++ core code, COM interface class (from IDL) and the COM implementation which inherits from the other two.

Comment: @John: We didn't use inheritance between `COM` classes and the core classes, mainly because it would have caused diamond-inheritance, which is *bad* imo. `COM` classes just wraps the core classes, and there is **no logic** elsewhere than in the core classes.